# Unsubscribe from AfterCheck in Custom TreeView

Tags: c#, treeview

I'm creating a custom TreeView in C# inherited from a regular Forms.TreeView, and I need the checkbox to change when clicking the text of the node. That is done. However, the triggered AfterCheck event, sends it's EventArgs Action as unknown instead as by Mouse.

To solve this. I tried to change the Node, then create a new TreeViewEventArgs with the correct TreeViewAction, and firing AfterCheck.

```
#region Override OnNodeMouseClick
        /// <summary> Allows the node to change when it's name is clicked </summary>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        protected override void OnNodeMouseClick(TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNodeMouseClick(e);

            #region Get in which pixel the name begins
            TreeNode node = e.Node; //Stores the node
            int i = 0;              //Counter of how many parent nodes the node has

            #region Counts how many parent nodes the clicked node has
            while(node.Parent != null)
            { node = node.Parent; i++; }
            #endregion

            int margin = 40 + 20 * i; //Defines the pixel on which the name in the node starts
            #endregion

            if (e.X >= margin)
            {
                e.Node.Checked = !e.Node.Checked; //Changes th
                MouseClickEventArgs = new TreeViewEventArgs(e.Node, TreeViewAction.ByMouse);

                OnAfterCheck(MouseClickEventArgs);
            }
        }
        #endregion
```

However, this obviously causes the event to fire twice. Once with an unknown action and another with a ByMouse action.

The differentiation between the type of Action is needed for another part of the code and also is the reason the event shouldn't fire twice.

Thanks for your help